# ruby でスペースによるメソッドコールが可能な文脈は?

Tags: ruby

ruby ではスペースによって引数付きのメソッドコールを表すことができますが、これがどういうタイミングで可能なのかが分からないな、と思っています。

例えば、以下ではメソッドコールは成功します。

```
[1] pry(main)> ([1].take 1).to_s
=> "[1]"
```

しかし、以下では成功しません。

```
[2] pry(main)> true ? [1] : [0].take 1
SyntaxError: unexpected tINTEGER, expecting end-of-input
true ? [1] : [0].take 1
                      ^
```

この失敗している例において、文法的な解釈として、 `[0].take 1` をひとつのメソッドコールとして解釈してくれてもいいかと思いましたが、(それ以外に正しい式の木を構築する方法がないはずなので)そうはなっていない様子です。

#### 質問

ruby においてスペースによってメソッドコールができる文脈は何ですか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rubyの演算子順位表](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2foperator.html)を見ればいいと思います。
`()`は演算順位が一番高く、`()`なしは演算順位が一番低い(`()`なしについては公式のドキュメントが見つけられませんでしたが)ので、

```
true ? [1] : [0].take 1
```

は演算順位が高い`?:(条件演算子)`が先に解釈されて

```
(true ? [1] : [0].take) 1
```

と同じ意味になり、

```
[1] 1
```

という意味になるので文法エラーになるのだと思います。

> ruby においてスペースによってメソッドコールができる文脈は何ですか?

これについては、[rubyの演算子順位表](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2foperator.html)を見ながら適宜確認するしかないと思います。
(普通はそれは面倒なので怪しいところには`()`をつけてしまいます。)

Comment: 演算子による expr が常に先に評価されていって、残った term 達はメソッドコールとして右から処理されるのだとすれば理解できる気がしました。

Answer (score 0):

追記として、どうやら、 スペースによる関数適用の結合順序は、 `?:` より下で、 `=`(代入) より上の様子です。

```
result = some_method arg
some_condition arg and return
```

これらは、両方ともスペースによるメソッド適用がなされてから、代入なり and 移行の評価なりが行われている様子です。